# How to check commit present on particular branch or not

Tags: git, gerrit, repository

My intention is to verify whether the particular commit is present on a given branch or not. I know we can use

git branch --contains commit id

But it needs that repo to be cloned in your local machine. Is there any way I can get this information by just querying gerrit?? I don't want to clone each and every repo..

Comment: Log on to the server that hosts the repositories, and run the command there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this via git commands. The git protocols all tell the remote server about the heads you have and the remote server generates a pack with all the commits you are missing – that’s not what you are looking for.

You either need to have ssh access to the server and run the git command there, or the server provides an API of some other kind that you can access. The gerrit server has a [HTTP API](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/rest-api.html), but it only gives you access to Code Review information.

Comment: Can you please give me example that how to connect through ssh and any command to run there??

Comment: Well, you need to set up ssh access – you can find a lot of tutorials for that on the internet and how to do that depends on the specific system your server is running. Then you can simply log onto to the server from any linux terminal using `ssh yourserver`, `cd` into the directory with the repo and then run `git branch --contains *commit*` in there.